# Solving an equation with quadratic and ratio constraints

Tags: problem-solving

I'm struggling with a problem that involves finding all real numbers $p$ that satisfy certain conditions related to a quadratic equation. The equation is as follows:

$$p x^2+\left(1+p^2\right) x+p=0$$

The problem asks me to find all values of $p$ for which this equation has two distinct solutions whose ratio is equal to 2. I've attempted to solve this by using the quadratic formula and manipulating the expressions to satisfy the ratio constraint, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Specifically, how do I use the quadratic formula to find the roots of the equation? I know I have to set the ratio of the two roots equal to 2:

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=2$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include in your post what you attempted to do to solve the problem and what level of algebra you are comfortable with.  Setting context of that sort for problems you post on this site is helpful to respondents so that they will have a better idea of how to reply to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases:
1.
$$px^2+(1+p^2)x+p=(px+1)(x+p)=0$$
$$px_1+1=0\quad\text{and}\quad x_2+p=0$$
$$x_1=-\dfrac{1}{p}\quad\text{and}\quad x_2=-p$$
$$\frac{x_2}{x_1}=\dfrac{-p}{-\frac{1}{p}}=p^2=2$$
$$p=\pm\sqrt{2}$$
2.
$$px^2+(1+p^2)x+p=(px+1)(x+p)=0$$
$$px_2+1=0\quad\text{and}\quad x_1+p=0$$
$$x_2=-\dfrac{1}{p}\quad\text{and}\quad x_1=-p$$
$$\frac{x_2}{x_1}=\dfrac{-\frac{1}{p}}{-p}=\dfrac{1}{p^2}=2$$
$$p=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
So $p\in\left\{\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$

Comment: It says the answer is 0, do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: If p=0 the equation became "x=0"

Answer (score 0):

To apply the quadratic formula as you ask about, the discriminant of the given polynomial is $ \ \Delta \ = \ (1 + p^2)^2 \ - \ 4·p^2 \ = \ 1 - 2p^2 + p^4 \ = \ (1 - p^2)^2 \ \ . \ $  If we call the roots of the equation $ \ r \ $ and $ \ 2r \ \ , \ $ their difference  is $ \ 2r - r \ = \ r \ = \ \frac{ \sqrt{\Delta} }{p} \ = \ \frac{|1 \ - \ p^2|}{p} \ \ . \ $  Since the sum of the two roots is $ \ 3r \ = \  -\frac{1 \ + \ p^2}{p} \ \ , \ $ we have two cases to solve for $ \ r \ $ and $ \ p \ \ . \ $

Alternatively,  for the roots $ \ r \ $ and $ \ 2r \ \ , \ $ we have the factorization $ \ px^2 + (1 + p^2)x + p $ $ = \ p·(x - r)·(x - 2r) \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  Comparing the coefficients gives us two equations:
$$ p \ \ = \ \ p·2r^2 \ \ , \ \ 1 \ + \ p^2 \ \ = \ \ p·(-3r) \ \ . $$

Since we must have $ \ p \ \neq \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the first equation tells us the the two roots are given by $ \ r \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ \ . \ $  Inserting either of these values into the second equation $ \ p^2 + 3rp + 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ $ leads to  four possible values for $ \ p \ \ $ (as also shown by **Fabio Caiazzo**). These correspond to two "upward-" and two "downward-opening" parabolas.

Comment: Can you explain how to solve this math problem like I'm a 5-year-old who has never seen anything like it before?